# Running a script periodically via a GPO

Tags: windows, group-policy, scripting

I search a way to run a script each hour via a GPO accross every computers on a domain.
The only way I found is a GPO which create a scheduled task.

Anybody have a better idea ?

Answer (score 3):

A scheduled task ***is*** the way to do this. Use a GPO to set this up, by all means, but you can only do startup, shutdown, logon and logoff with GPO.

What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: I just want to run a script, but I don't like the idea to create something on each computer. Once it is created, it has to be managed (ie deleted when no more needed. This is a problem with roaming machines, and some other situations).

Comment: @GregoryMOUSSAT Well, that's the recommended method. You could write your script to handle those scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

The method you've found, create a Scheduled Task, is the only way I've found to do that. It works as advertised.